# Detecting declared package variables in perl

Tags: perl, variables, declaration

Given

```
# package main;
our $f;
sub f{}
sub g {}
1;
```

How can I determine that `$f`, but not `$g`, has been declared?  Off the cuff, I'd thought that `*{main::g}{SCALAR}` might be undefined, but it is a *bona fide* SCALAR ref.

Background:  I'd like to import a variable into `main::`, but carp or croak if that variable is already declared.

**EDIT** Added an `f` subroutine in response to @DVK's initial answer.

**ANSWER (2010-07-27)**

This isn't easy, but it is possible.

An [`eval` technique](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3335425/detecting-declared-package-variables-in-perl/3336806#3336806) is most portable, working on perls older than 5.10.  In more recent perls, introspective modules like [`Devel::Peek`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3335425/detecting-declared-package-variables-in-perl/3336535#3336535) and [`B`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3335425/detecting-declared-package-variables-in-perl/3337046#3337046) can discriminate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I gave it my best, even going so far as trying to ask `eval STRING` whether `$main::f` had been declared via `our` or `my`. (This required duping, closing, and later restoring `STDERR` to cut down on the chattiness.) Once you've changed packages, those declarations no longer seem visible on a temporary switchback.

The technique below will detect whether `$f` has been declared via

```
use vars qw/ $f /;
```

Code below:

```
package MyModule;

use warnings;
use strict;

# using $f will confuse the compiler, generating
# warnings of 'Variable "%f" is not available'
# although we're going for $main::f
my $__f = "from MyModule";

my %IMPORT_OK = (
  '$f' => [f => \$__f],
);

sub import {
  my($pkg,@imports) = @_;
  my $callpkg = caller;

  die "I don't speak your dirty Pig-Latin"
    if $callpkg !~ /\A\w+(::\w+)*\z/ ||
       grep !/\A[\$@%]\w+\z/, @imports;

  foreach my $name (@imports) {
    my($sym,$ref) = @{ $IMPORT_OK{$name} || [] };
    die "unknown import: $name" unless $sym;

    open my $saverr, ">&", \*STDERR or die "dup STDERR: $!";
    close STDERR;

    my $declared = eval qq{
      package $callpkg;
      my(undef)=$name;
      1;
    };

    open STDERR, ">&", $saverr or print "restore STDERR: $!";
    die "${callpkg}::$sym already exists" if $declared;

    {
      no strict 'refs';
      *{$callpkg . "::" . $sym} = $ref;
    }
  }
}

1;
```

Comment: +1, and I don't normally upvote stringish eval()s.  :)  This is more-or-less my current approach.  Importantly, the eval check here does *not* invoke a tie()d scalar's FETCH method -- that'd be No Good (tm).  I wonder, could local()izing $SIG{__WARN__} take care of the error messages?

Comment: Yes, FWIW, in my testing if you localize the _\_WARN\_\_ handler (and $@, too, out of politeness) before the eval, you silence the errors without file descriptor duppery.

Answer (score 4):

**SUMMARY**

At this point, after fairly extensive research, I am of a firm opinion that in a situation when a symbol table entry with the name "X" was declared but not assigned to,  it is **impossible to generically distinguish** which of the reference types in a glob was actually declared witout using deep probing of Devel:: stuff.

In other words, you can tell only the following 2 distinct situations:

1. X was not declared at all (symbol table entry does not exist)
2. X was declared and some of the glob types were actually assigned to.

   In this second case,

   - You **can** find WHICH of the glob types were assigned to and which were not
   - BUT, you **can not** figure out which of the non-assigned-to glob types were declared-and-unassigned vs. which were not declared at all.

   In other words, for `our $f = 1; our @f;`; we can tell that `$main::f` is a scalar;
   but we can NOT tell whether `@f` and `%f` were declared or not - it is not distinguishable at all from `our $f = 1; our %f;` .

   Please note that the subroutine definitions follow this second rule as well, but declaring a named sub automatically assigns it a value (the code block), so you can never have a sub name in a "declared but not assigned to" state (caveat: might not be true for prototypes??? no clue).

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**

Well,  very limited (and IMHO somewhat fragile) solution to distinguishing a scalar from a subroutine could be to use UNIVERSAL::can:

```
use strict; 
our $f; 
sub g {};
foreach my $n ("f","g","h") {
    # First off, check if we are in main:: namespace, 
    # and if we are, that we are a scalar
    no strict "refs"; 
    next unless exists $main::{$n} && *{"main::$n"}; 
    use strict "refs"; 
    # Now, we are a declared scalr, unless we are a executable subroutine:
    print "Declared: \$$n\n" unless UNIVERSAL::can("main",$n)
}
```

Result:

```
Declared: $f
```

Please note that `{SCALAR}` does not seem to work to weed out non-scalars in my testing - it happily passed through `@A` and `%H` if I declared them and added to the loop.

**UPDATE**

I tried brian d foy's approach from Chapter 8 of "Mastering perl" and somehow was unable to get it to work for scalars, hashes or arrays; but as noted below by draegtun it works for subroutines or for variables **that were assigned to already**:

```
> perl5.8 -we '{use strict; use Data::Dumper; 
  our $f; sub g {}; our @A=(); sub B{}; our $B; our %H=();
  foreach my $n ("f","g","h","STDOUT","A","H","B") {
      no strict "refs"; 
      next unless exists $main::{$n};
      print "Exists: $n\n";
      if ( defined ${$n}) { print "Defined scalar: $n\n"}; 
      if ( defined @{$n}) { print "Defined ARRAY: $n\n"}; 
      if ( defined %{$n}) { print "Defined HASH: $n\n"}; 
      if ( defined &{$n}) { print "Defined SUB: $n\n"}; 
      use strict "refs";}}'       

Exists: f
Exists: g
Defined SUB: g           <===== No other defined prints worked
Exists: STDOUT
Exists: A
Exists: H
Exists: B
Defined SUB: B           <===== No other defined prints worked
```

Comment: +1 Excellent attempt.  FWIW, I'm not sure that \*{name}{SCALAR} *is ever false* -- it's the exists test (which can be done `strict`-ly) that skips "h".  This check fails, however, if sub f{} is also defined.

Comment: @pilcrow - yeah, that's exactly what I meant in the last paragraph. And you're right about `$f` + `&f`...  as I said this was kinda fragile and limited.

Comment: @pilcrow @DVK From perlref: "`*foo{THING}` returns `undef` if that particular THING hasn't been used yet, except in the case of scalars. `*foo{SCALAR}` returns a reference to an anonymous scalar if `$foo` hasn't been used yet. This might change in a future release." This makes `&main::f` versus `$main::f` a confounding case.

Answer (score 3):

Older perls (pre-5.10) will always have something in the scalar slot.

On newer perls, it appears that the old behavior is mimicked when you
try to do *FOO{SCALAR}.

You can use the B introspection module to check the scalar slot, though:

```
# package main;
our $f;
sub f {}
sub g {}

use B;
use 5.010;
if ( ${ B::svref_2object(\*f)->SV } ) {
   say "f: Thar be a scalar tharrr!";
}
if ( ${ B::svref_2object(\*g)->SV } ) {
   say "g: Thar be a scalar tharrr!";
}

1;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check for a defined subroutine like so:

```
say 'g() defined in main' if defined &{'main::g'};
```

Unfortunately the same method only works on package variable if a value has been assigned:

```
our $f = 1;
say '$f defined with value in main' if defined ${'main::f'};
```

/I3az/

Answer (score 1):

Devel::Peek appears to be able to distinguish between used and unused things in the SCALAR slot:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Devel::Peek;

our $f;
sub f { }
sub g { }

Dump(*f);
Dump(*g);
```

The output is:

```
SV = PVGV(0x187360c) at 0x182c0f4
  REFCNT = 3
  FLAGS = (MULTI,IN_PAD)
  NAME = "f"
  NAMELEN = 1
  GvSTASH = 0x24a084    "main"
  GP = 0x1874bd4
    SV = 0x182c0a4
    REFCNT = 1
    IO = 0x0
    FORM = 0x0  
    AV = 0x0
    HV = 0x0
    CV = 0x24a234
    CVGEN = 0x0
    LINE = 6
    FILE = "c:\temp\foo.pl"
    FLAGS = 0xa
    EGV = 0x182c0f4 "f"
SV = PVGV(0x187362c) at 0x18514dc
  REFCNT = 2
  FLAGS = (MULTI,IN_PAD)
  NAME = "g"
  NAMELEN = 1
  GvSTASH = 0x24a084    "main"
  GP = 0x1874cbc
    SV = 0x0
    REFCNT = 1
    IO = 0x0
    FORM = 0x0  
    AV = 0x0
    HV = 0x0
    CV = 0x1865234
    CVGEN = 0x0
    LINE = 8
    FILE = "c:\temp\foo.pl"
    FLAGS = 0xa
    EGV = 0x18514dc "g"
```

The lines of interest are under the `GP =` section, specifically SV, AV, HV, and CV (scalar, array, hash, and code, respectively). Note that the dump of `*g` shows `SV = 0x0`. Unfortunately, there doesn't appear to be a programmatic way to get this information. A blunt instrument approach would be to capture the output of `Dump()` and parse it.

Comment: And older perls (pre-5.10) will always have something in the scalar slot...

On newer perls, you can test for `${B::svrev_2object(\\*f)->SV}==0`